# Finite coloring of Odd natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $\mathbb{N}_{0} = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. Let $a_{1} , \dots , a_{n} \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{0\}$ such that whenever the odd natural numbers are finitely colored $c : 2 \mathbb{N}_{0} + 1 \rightarrow [k]$, there $\exists x_{1} , \dots , x_{n} \in 2 \mathbb{N}_{0} + 1$ with the same color such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} a_{i} = 0$.
>
> Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} = 0$.

I was thinking of perhaps going by contradiction. Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \ne 0$. Then we can construct some coloring $c : 2 \mathbb{N}_{0} + 1 \rightarrow [k]$ such that there is no such $x_{1} , \dots , x_{n}$. If I have $a_{i} = \frac{p_{i}}{q_{i}}$, then I equivalently have to show that there is no $\{x_{i} : i \in [n]\} \subseteq 2 \mathbb{N}_{0} + 1$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} p_{i} t_{i} = 0$, where $t_{i} = \prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \ne i}}^{n} q_{j}$

The main difficulty in this approach is finding the coloring that would prevent any monochromatic $\vec{x}$ from existing and I have not made much progress.